# Resources$NotFoundException for .PNG drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

Here is my `AppCompatImageView`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_logo_initial"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:src="@drawable/launcher_logo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/custom_fb_btn" />
```

Here is my launcher_logo image:

[image]

Here is the error I got on a Nexus 5X running Android 8.1.0:

```
Caused by android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView


Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Unable to find resource ID #0x7f08011a
```

I have not encountered this error before. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with this weird `drawable-v24` folder. The `launcher_logo.png` lives in every drawable folder below except for the `drawable-v24` folder where only 1 file lives:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Is the issue happening on all devices old and new?

Comment: Just to clear the doubt, add the other png sizes to this drawable-v24 folder.